# Debian 10 Buster can't renew DHCP as client, when IPv6 is disabled

Tags: debian, dhcp, ipv6, dhclient, debian-buster

After I upgraded Debian 9 to 10 Buster server lost network connection after 24 hours since reboot, I think problem is it can't renew IP address from DHCP server.

In `/var/lib/dhcp` I see the file `dhclient.eth0.leases` with expired date inside.

This service was ok with Debian 9, with Debian 10 I see this error:

```
root@debian:~# systemctl status networking.service
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled;
vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-07-25 15:18:02
CEST; 2h 39min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 380 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment
(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 380 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 25 15:18:01 debian-2gb-nbg1-2 dhclient[402]: DHCPREQUEST for
116.203.xx.xx on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 25 15:18:01 debian-2gb-nbg1-2 dhclient[402]: DHCPACK of
116.203.xx.xx from 172.31.1.1
Jul 25 15:18:01 debian-2gb-nbg1-2 ifup[380]: DHCPACK of 116.203.xx.xx
from 172.31.1.1
Jul 25 15:18:01 debian-2gb-nbg1-2 dhclient[402]: bound to
116.203.xx.xx -- renewal in 34516 seconds.
Jul 25 15:18:01 debian-2gb-nbg1-2 ifup[380]: bound to 116.203.xx.xx
-- renewal in 34516 seconds.
Jul 25 15:18:02 debian-2gb-nbg1-2 ifup[380]: RTNETLINK answers:
Permission denied
Jul 25 15:18:02 debian-2gb-nbg1-2 ifup[380]: ifup: failed to bring up eth0:0
Jul 25 15:18:02 debian-2gb-nbg1-2 systemd[1]: networking.service: Main
process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 25 15:18:02 debian-2gb-nbg1-2 systemd[1]: networking.service:
Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 25 15:18:02 debian-2gb-nbg1-2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise
network interfaces.
```

Thanks for any help.

Edit:
problem solved, looks like Debian 10 doesn't like disabling of IPv6 by the same way as v9 do.

**If anyone knows how to disable IPv6 in Buster, let us know.**

```
# disabling of IPv6 in Debian 9, not working in Debian 10
/etc/sysctl.conf
    net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
    net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
    net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
```

Comment: Any log file entries, also from the DHCP server?

Comment: this is a VPS server so log from dhcp server is not available, but I found what is wrong, now just how to solve it?

Comment: Looks like "RTNETLINK answers: Permission denied" might be related to ipv6. Has its enabled/disabled status changed because of the upgrade?

Comment: check the Edit in the main post

Comment: Please post the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: `cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

#  loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg`

Comment: `cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    dns-nameservers 213.133.xx.xx

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet6 static
    address 2a01:4f8:c2c:xxxx::1/64
    gateway fe80::1
    post-up route add -A inet6 default gw fe80::1%eth0 || true
    pre-down route del -A inet6 default gw fe80::1%eth0 || true`

Comment: I personally kill ipv6 by recompiling my kernel without ipv6 support. It is the only way to be sure. Some crap will surely happen what re-enables it...

Comment: I see the same on aws and virtualbox vm's without disabling ipv6

Comment: @Roman_G Did you found any solution with disabled ipv6? I disable ipv6 without sysctl using grub: /etc/default/grub GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1" update-grub And I wait to see if it works.

Comment: Finally there is no way to make it work with ipv6 disabled. I had to replace dhcp with static ip configuration.

Comment: comments are nevertheless an answer